# Can't update innerHTML on "instagram.com/direct" through javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, instagram

I am making an extension for google chrome to allow me to quickly type emojies, for example if the word 'heart' is typed in betwen two colons, the extension will automatically change it into ❤️.
It works on certain websites (it works here on stackoverflow) but it wont work on IG, specifically in IG direct messages (which was the original purpose of the extension).
I have tried just changing it directly from the console but it isnt changing. [image: attempting to change message through console]

The code is available here:
[github repo](https://github.com/stcksmsh/EmojiType)
There are definitely other issues with the project, and if you notice any please let me know.

I have tried to eddit innerHTML, innerText and other properties that seemed relevant but that changed nothing.
I tried changing it directly from the console, but as is shown in the picture above it has no effect.

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [@wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) in the comments
I ended up using a combination of `document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null);` and `document.execCommand('insertText',false,text);`.
The first command will select all relevant text and the second will insert new text. Since everything is selected the second command will overwrite the contents with the new text.